# ESRI AddFeatures call on rest endpoint with attributes

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-rest-api

I can add a line feature via the rest endpoint with my hand crafted call from C#. However, if i add any attributes to the call it will fail and say unable to perform operation.
All of the fields in the sde feature class are nullable.

Comment: I am seeing an error in the ags logs.....The field is not nullable. [SHAPE_STLength__]. The geometry is not Z-aware

Comment: this is not a z-aware dataset in any way